# How to use URL redirect in Google Chrome Extension in Manifest V3

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am new to developing Google Chrome Extensions. After extensive research, I cannot find really any useful Tips. Basically, what I want is after successfully logging in; the user is presented with a popup box (at this moment, options.html); where a user can check a checkbox (which if checked), does this change on this file. I do not have the function for the checkbox yet but I am needing to do the redirect first I think to make sure my extension would work for what I need it for but..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/selection.css">
<style>
        body, html {
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
        }
        .container {
            box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px 8px #181818;
            width: 400px;
            height: 300px;
            background: url("./Images/ShadowGhosts.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: auto;
            background-size: 400px 300px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: left;
            justify-content: left;
            flex-direction: column;
            font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
            user-select: none;
            color: goldenrod;
        }

        .black-input {
            color: red
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Select Which one you Want:</legend>

    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="black-input" id="scales" name="scales">
             <!-- checked> -->
      <label for="scales">Ears</label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="horns" name="horns">
      <label for="horns">Horns</label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</div>
</body>
```

and this is my manifest file:

```
{
    "name": "Shadow Ghosts",
    "description": "Some Cool Description",
    "version": "1.1",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "./JS/background.js"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "./Images/SG.png",
            "32": "./Images/SG.png",
            "48": "./Images/SG.png",
            "128": "./Images/SG.png"
        }
    },
    "icons": {
            "16": "./Images/SG.png",
            "32": "./Images/SG.png",
            "48": "./Images/SG.png",
            "128": "./Images/SG.png"

    },

    "content_scripts": [{
            "all_frames": true,
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["JS/content-script.js"]
        },
        {
            "run_at": "document_start",
            "matches": ["*://localhost/tulc/public/exemple/wc*"],
            "js": ["JS/cookie-fix.js"]
        }
    ],

    "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting", "webRequest", "declarativeNetRequest"]
}
```

And lastly, this is my background script:

```
let color = "#3AA757";

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({ color });
    console.log('Default background color set to ,color');
});


// chrome.webRequest.onSendHeaders.addListener(function (e){
//  chrome.tabs.query({
//      active:true,
//      currentWindow:true
//  },
//  function (tabs){

//  });},
//  {
//  urls:["<all_urls>"],
//  types: ["xmlhttprequest"]
// },["requestHeaders"]);
```

In my background script, I used an older example to try to create my own code but it did not work as I had to comment it out. Can someone please point me in the right direction on:

1.) How to do a URL Redirect (From: Yahoo.com To: Google.com)
2.) How to add data to each checkbox if checked
and Lastly:
3.) How to use the data from the checkbox to modify data on the redirected page?

Comment: Use `declarativeNetRequest` API. See the documentation for examples and more info.

Comment: @wOxxOm , do you happen to have a video of it somewhere. I learn best by watching it how it's being used.